# IE8 link background color not changing on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, hover

So, I have an issue with the hover state of a link in IE8. Code is as follows:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="/" class="home">Home</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#navigation {
    float: right;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 23px
}

#navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 120%;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 104px;
}

#navigation a.home {
    background-color: #f4e034;
}

#navigation a.home:hover {
    background-color: #fffbd4;
}
```

Now, this works fine in every other browser I have tested in (Chrome, Safari, FF, IE6, and IE7), it just won't change the background color of the link in IE8 on hover.

I have tried adding `display: block` and `display: inline-block` to the `a` element. I have also tried adding `!important` after the background-color in the hover tag. I have also made sure that there are no other elements in the CSS that is affecting this.

Googling this problem gives me a bunch of things regarding the IE8 beta, which this is not. It also gives me answers for menu related links, which this is not. It gives me answers for things being affected that aren't background-color. And it gives me things where changing the font-color works, but not the background-color (neither works in my case).

Just wondering if anyone else has ever noticed this issue and has something they can provide on this. Let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious, have you tried adding border (or any other style like font-weight:bold;) in the :hover state and see if that takes effect?

Comment: I wonder, does removing the declaration for its default background color cause it to work? (like removing the rules that are contained in `#navigation a.home { [...] }`)

Comment: I tested this code in IE8 and it works fine. Are you sure there is not conflicting code elsewhere? http://jsfiddle.net/N4zUN/

Comment: I've checked your code. And it works as expected. [http://jsfiddle.net/TvUtZ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/TvUtZ/1/)

Comment: @pixelfreak @Nightfirecat @Tank @Molecule I have tried adding other elements to the hover state, that being font-weight, font-size, border, and color, nothing works. I also tried removing the a.home property and it still doesn't work. I updates this jsFiddle, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/N4zUN/2/) with all of the code on the page, including all of the CSS. And it does indeed appear to work on jsFiddle, but it most definitely doesn't work on my page, and that is everything on that page.

Comment: I have recreated your code as an html page and tested in real Internet Explorer 8 (no compatibility mode etc.) and your code works completely as expected... Now that is cool! I just dropped down to IE7 mode and got your outdated browser pop-up. I love it!

Comment: @tw16 well that's three people now and myself that have seen it work in various situations. So it should most definitely work, especially because it works in IE6 and IE7. So I guess something that I haven't thought of must be affecting this. Thanks for helping everyone, I will see if I can find what else could be affecting this.

Comment: having a similar pb here. Just to say that Arak is not "making up" his problem. Arak, did you find what was the solution in the end ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the seem problem as yours. I tried every way as you did but it has no use.

My final solution was to set a background-color on the element you need to hover, then it worked.

I felt shocked at that time and I don't know why still now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DOCTYPE specified on your HTML page? It might seem obvious, but I've had similar problems with the :hover state in IE8 - especially when editing old sites.

The solution for me was to add a DOCTYPE above the opening HTML tag on your HTML page

!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

I hope this helps!